# object properties overriding type issue

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function in typescript to override the default values of an object with the values given in another object.

Basically it should take in 2 objects and add the non-null properties of 2nd object to the first object and return the modified obj.
I could use destructuring like this `{...a, ...b}` but then if there are any null values in the `b` object, those would override the values in `a` object.

Here is a function I wrote, unfortunately, can't understand what typescript is complaining about.

```
function assignIfPresent<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(origObj: T, additions:Partial<T> ) {
    for (const propName in additions) {
        if (additions[propName])
            origObj[propName] = additions[propName];
    }

    return origObj;
}
```

error at `origObj[propName]`

```
const propName: Extract<keyof T, string>
Type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>]'.
```

UseCase:

```
class User {
    public firstName!: string;
    public lastName!: string;
    public gender?: string;
}

const newUser = new User();

newUser.lastName = "Biden"

const userDetails: Partial<User> = {
    firstName: "Joe",
    lastName: undefined,
}

console.log(assignIfPresent(newUser, userDetails)) //[LOG]: { "lastName": "Biden", "firstName": "Joe" } 
console.log({...newUser, ...userDetails}) //[LOG]: { "firstName": "Joe" }
```

would be great if anyone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest du use lodash's `pickBy` to remove falsy values

```
import { pickBy } from 'lodash';

class User {
    public firstName!: string;
    public lastName!: string;
    public gender?: string;
}

const newUser = new User();

newUser.lastName = "Biden"

const userDetails: Partial<User> = {
    firstName: "Joe",
    lastName: undefined,
}

console.log({...newUser, ...pickBy(userDetails, _ => !!_)})
```

See stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vthhuy?file=index.ts

Comment: This solution works. I checked it out on stackbiltz. Thank you so much.
I would love to know what is the cause of the error too. Would be great if you can help me understand it.

Comment: Because the loop also includes `undefined`. `for(const propName in { lastName: 'foo' }) console.log(propName)` prints `lastName`and `undefined`, `for(const propName in { }) console.log(propName)` prints just `undeifned`.

Comment: I tried executing `for (const propName in {lastName:"bkjsdb"}) console.log((propName === undefined || propName === null) ? "undefined1" : propName);`. I was not able to get `undefined` to be printed on the console. Am i missing something here? please correct me if i am wrong.